# Approximation percentage of Administration costs based of Revenues

Tags: expenses

Sorry, I'm really naive about the finance and accounting fields.

I'm trying to contribute to some Christian relief/missionary/medical organizations, and trying to go through their balance sheets, Revenues and expenses, etc.

Correct me if I'm wrong but one good measure of efficiency is by evaluating the administration costs.

I came across the following Christian organizations financial accountability evaluation website:

https://briinstitute.com/mw/ministry.php?ein=581437002

Could someone please tell me if it's correct to say that in the following Revenues and Expenses sheet that an approximation percentage of Administration costs based of Revenues is?

((Management and general)/(Total expenses)) x 100 = ($40,404,423/$701,347,088) x 100 = 5.76%

[image]